# Can a Samsung Galaxy S2 detect a signature on the screen?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Im working on a project where I hope to use an android mobile device to query a database and retrieve information. Part of the project involves the user to sign the phone with their signature so that it is sent back to the database. By signing I mean a manual signature using pen input on the screen. Is this possible? Does anyone know of any android phones out there (preferably Samsung) that does this? Thanks

Comment: It has capacitive screen, so most pens won't work anyway. But there are 'special' pens that will work.

Comment: Signature comparison should be done using vector comparison rather than comparing painted bitmaps; People generally don't get their signatures exactly the same every time so a vector-based algorithm could allow variance within given parameters at each change of direction. Measurement of speed could also be desirable to avoid fraudsters carefully imitating a signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. Signature recognition is an incredibly advanced topic and there are no built-in apps / libraries you can leverage. It takes expert humans to recognize signatures and they still generally can't give certainties. There are ways you can detect pattern and image similarity in Java but there is going to be some fuzzing involved and it will likely not be as accurate as you desire

**Update**

If you are simply looking to record the signature you can capture touch events via `View.onTouchEvent()`. You can see an example of using this to in the [Touch Paint API Demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html). In addition to drawing the coordinates on the screen you can record them to a database to be re-assembled later.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Im not looking for my database to authenticate the signature. All I want is for my phone to record the signature in the same way that UPS get you to sign for a delivery on a portable device. Is this not possible on a smart phone?

Comment: If you are simply looking to record signatures that is just a very basic matter of taking touch events and recording them.

Comment: Thanks you. I'll check out that Touch Paint API Demo now. Thats exactly what I was looking for